# Pointer to Pointer with argv

Tags: c

Based on my understanding of pointer to pointer to an array of characters,

```
% ./pointer one two

argv           
+----+          +----+
| .  |   --->   | .  |  ---> "./pointer\0"
+----+          +----+
                | .  |  ---> "one\0"
                +----+
                | .  |  ---> "two\0"
                +----+
```

From the code:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    printf("Value of argv[1]: %s", argv[1]);
}
```

My question is, Why is argv[1] acceptable? Why is it not something like (*argv)[1]?

My understanding steps:

1. Take argv, dereference it.
2. It should return the address of the array of pointers to characters.
3. Using pointer arithmetics to access elements of the array.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's more convenient to think of `[]` as an operator for pointers rather than arrays; it's used with both, but since arrays decay to pointers array indexing still makes sense if it's looked at this way.  So essentially it offsets, then dereferences, a pointer.

So with `argv[1]`, what you've really got is `*(argv + 1)` expressed with more convenient syntax.  This gives you the second `char *` in the block of memory pointed at by `argv`, since `char *` is the type `argv` points to, and `[1]` offsets `argv` by `sizeof(char *)` bytes then dereferences the result.

`(*argv)[1]` would dereference `argv` first with `*` to get the first pointer to `char`, then offset that by `1 * sizeof(char)` bytes, then dereferences *that* to get a `char`.  This gives the second character in the first string of the group of strings pointed at by `argv`, which is obviously not the same thing as `argv[1]`.

So think of an indexed array variable as a pointer being operated on by an "offset then dereference a pointer" operator.

Comment: Yes, I had the confusion of why we didn't need to derefrence argv, first but it turns out I forgotten that it's equal to *(argv + n), where n is the index subscript.

Answer (score 16):

Because `argv` is a pointer to pointer to `char`, it follows that `argv[1]` is a pointer to `char`.  The `printf()` format `%s` expects a pointer to char argument and prints the null-terminated array of characters that the argument points to.  Since `argv[1]` is not a null pointer, there is no problem.

`(*argv)[1]` is also valid C, but `(*argv)` is equivalent to `argv[0]` and is a pointer to `char`, so `(*argv)[1]` is the second character of `argv[0]`, which is `/` in your example.

Answer (score 5):

Indexing a pointer as an array implicitly dereferences it. `p[0]` is `*p`, `p[1]` is `*(p + 1)`, etc.