# Not able to get argv[0] in x86 assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16722942/1651941) indicates that `ESP + 4` points to `argv[0]`. But I'm not able to make it work:

```
        .section .text

        .globl _start

_start:

        movl 8(%esp), %ebx
        movl $1, %eax
        int $0x80
```

And now when I try to execute this:

```
$ as --32 argv.s -o argv.o
$ ld -m elf_i386 argv.o -o argv
$ ./argv 2
$ echo $?
16
```

It displays `16` although I'm expecting 16 here. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: `0x10` looks like a reasonable value for the low byte of a pointer.  You get `0` if there are no args so `argv[1]` is NULL, right?  Anyway, dereference another time if you want a byte holding an ASCII character code from the pointed-to string.  (remember that a Linux exit status is only 1 byte wide.)

Comment: Use GDB to single-step your code so you can dump stack memory more than 1 byte at a time, and easily look at a pointer value + what it points to.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks, stepping via GDB was helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Peter's comment, I was finally able to figure out the answer. Since `argv` is a [pointer to pointer to `char`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7631282/1651941), in the first dereference you will get an address which is a pointer to a character. Dereferencing it again will give you the desired result:

```
        .section .text

        .globl _start

_start:

        movl 8(%esp), %ebx
        movl (%ebx), %ebx
        movl $1, %eax
        int $0x80
```

On executing it:

```
$ ./argv 1
49
```

49 is the expected result, which is the [ASCII character](http://ee.hawaii.edu/~tep/EE160/Book/chap4/subsection2.1.1.1.html) of `1`.